# I added a cookie rain into my site, just for fun for my asignment, but how can I make it only fill the space it has?

Tags: javascript, html, css

thanks for reading this and trying to help! :)

So, I'm doing this assignment for school and for fun and bonus points, I added a cookie rain that fills the full screen, copied a code from the internet and edited it to fit my needs. But when I go into windowed, you see this vertical and horizontal scroll bar and I want to avoid that. So what I want is that it only fills the screen it is presented, even when it's in windowed, so that the cookies don't go outside of the given resolution.

And by the way, I want my site usable by every resolution.

Here is my HTML-code:

```js
var image = "rsz_perfectcookie.png"; //Image path should be given here
var no = 320; // No of images should fall
var time = 0; // Configure whether image should disappear after x seconds (0=never):
var speed = 4; // Fix how fast the image should fall
var i, dwidth = 100,
  dheight = 100;
var nht = dheight;
var toppos = 0;

if (document.all) {
  var ie4up = 1;
} else {
  var ie4up = 0;
}

if (document.getElementById && !document.all) {
  var ns6up = 1;
} else {
  var ns6up = 0;
}

function getScrollXY() {
  var scrOfX = 10,
    scrOfY = 10;
  if (typeof(window.pageYOffset) == 'number') {
    //Netscape compliant
    scrOfY = window.pageYOffset;
    scrOfX = window.pageXOffset;
  } else if (document.body && (document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop)) {
    //DOM compliant
    scrOfY = document.body.scrollTop;
    scrOfX = document.body.scrollLeft;
  } else if (document.documentElement &&
    (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop)) {
    //IE6 standards compliant mode
    scrOfY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    scrOfX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
  }
  return [scrOfX, scrOfY];
}

var timer;

function ranrot() {

  var a = getScrollXY()
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  toppos = a[1];
  dheight = nht + a[1];
  //alert(dheight);

  timer = setTimeout('ranrot()', 200);
}

ranrot();

function iecompattest() {
  if (document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat") {
    return document.documentElement;
  } else {
    return document.body;
  }

}
if (ns6up) {
  dwidth = window.innerWidth;
  dheight = window.innerHeight;
} else if (ie4up) {
  dwidth = iecompattest().clientWidth;
  dheight = iecompattest().clientHeight;
}

nht = dheight;

var cv = new Array();
var px = new Array(); //position variables
var py = new Array(); //position variables
var am = new Array(); //amplitude variables
var sx = new Array(); //step variables
var sy = new Array(); //step variables

for (i = 0; i < no; ++i) {
  cv[i] = 0;
  px[i] = Math.random() * (dwidth - 100); // set position variables
  py[i] = Math.random() * dheight; // set position variables
  am[i] = Math.random() * 1.5; // set amplitude variables
  sx[i] = 0.02 + Math.random() / 10; // set step variables
  sy[i] = 0.7 + Math.random(); // set step variables
  document.write("<div id=\"dot" + i + "\" style=\"POSITION: absolute; Z-INDEX: " + i + "; VISIBILITY: visible; TOP: 15px;LEFT: 15px;\"><img src='" + image + "' border=\"0\"><\/div>");
}

function animation() { // animation function
  for (i = 0; i < no; ++i) { // iterate for every dot
    py[i] += sy[i];
    if (py[i] > dheight - 68) {
      px[i] = Math.random() * (dwidth - am[i] - 100);
      py[i] = toppos;
      sx[i] = 0.02 + Math.random() / 10;
      sy[i] = 0.7 + Math.random();
    }
    cv[i] += sx[i];
    document.getElementById("dot" + i).style.top = py[i] + "px";
    document.getElementById("dot" + i).style.left = px[i] + am[i] * Math.sin(cv[i]) + "px";
  }
  atime = setTimeout("animation()", speed);

}

function hideimage() {
  if (window.atime) clearTimeout(atime)
  for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
    document.getElementById("dot" + i).style.visibility = "hidden"
}
if (ie4up || ns6up) {
  animation();
  if (time > 0)
    setTimeout("hideimage()", time * 1000)
}
animation();
```

```html
>
<li><a href='home.html'><span>Home</span></a>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><a style="pointer-events: none;"><span>Alles over Steve</span></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Jeugd</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Ontstaan van Apple</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class='#'><a href='consoleedition.html'><span>Huldigingen en onderscheidingen</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class='has-sub'><a style="pointer-events: none;"><span>Boeken</span></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'><span>iWoz</span></a>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>The Art of Deception</span></a>
      </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'><span>Interviews</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="last"><a href='#'><span>Social media</span></a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>



  <div id="div1" style='margin-top: 100px;'>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
    <p>HEYHEY</p>
  </div>
```

The image of the cookie that is falling down is rsz_perfectcookie.png and is 64x64 pixels.

By the way, my menu is on the top of the screen and is horizontal and in a fixed position so it stays at the top. When the width is too small to fit all the words/titles it creates a horizontal dropdown mobile-device type of menu instead of the other one.

I don't think the CSS-code or the JavaScript-code is needed, but if it is let me know and I'll post it too.

Thanks!

Comment: ie4? Ns6? Is this the oldest Javascript known to man?

Comment: use css `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: @Kyle Is that really that bad?

Comment: @KevinKloet Where?

Comment: @LucBurgerjon Ie4 was released in 1997 and superceded by ie5 in 1999. It's a very old script, and these browser checks should be removed.

Comment: in your `document.write()` inside the style of the div like this: `document.write("<div id=\"dot" + i + "\" style=\"overflow:hidden;POSITION: absolute; Z-INDEX: " + i + "; VISIBILITY: visible; TOP: 15px;LEFT: 15px;\"><img src='" + image + "' border=\"0\"><\/div>");`

Comment: @Kyle But, it is still compatible? So no problem, really?

Comment: That's the thing with Javascript, it'll most likely still work, but whoever is grading your assignment is definitely going to know you ripped this off the internet and didn't bother to clean up old, useless code.

Comment: @KevinKloet I changed it to what you wrote, but it's still like that, when I go to windowed it is like it's still full screen. Can't I have it reload the website when you change resolution, or reload the javascript-part?

Comment: @Kyle My teacher doesn't care as long as it works, I'm in secondary school.

Comment: you could try to use media queries, [Using_media_queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), but note that this isn't compatible with ie 8 and lower. so the check for ie4up and ns6up is redundant.